# filter/limit django order_by

Tags: django, django-orm

Using the django ORM, Is there a way to limit or filter the scope of what order_by applies to?

```
Product.objects.filter(
    product_type__name=choices.PRODUCT_BOOK
).order_by(
    # need to order these last names by those 
    # who have a role code of "A01", then "B01"
    'contributor__writer__last_name'
)
```

Comment: where is role code attribute ? Writer object or Product ? show us ur models code

Comment: The role_code attribute is on the contributor.

Comment: Can u post your models code ?

Comment: Are you the same user? :S http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773867/filtering-the-order-by-relationship-in-django-orm

Comment: My colleague asked the same question, yes.  I can't find my post to mark as a duplicate though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even using raw SQL is not possible to apply an order by just to some rows. So the best way, order alls and group by role_code.

Also you can get contributors with `role_code` `"A01"` or `"B01"`, order them, then get the rest contributors excluding their `role_code` if is `"A01"` or `"B01"`. Then merge query results.

```
order_products = Product.objects.filter(
    product_type__name=choices.PRODUCT_BOOK
).filter(contributor__role_code__in=['A01','B01'])
.order_by(
    # need to order these last names by those 
    # who have a role code of "A01", then "B01"
    'contributor__writer__last_name'
)

non_order_products = Product.objects.filter(
    product_type__name=choices.PRODUCT_BOOK
).exclude(contributor__role_code__in=['A01','B01'])

final_result = order_products | non_order_products
```

Comment: This will limit products to only those who have contributors with a role_code of A01, B01.  That's not quite what is needed.  Rather the filter needs to apply only the order_by application, not to which products are being filtered.

Comment: @yekta u only want to order by contributors with a role_code of A01 or B01 ?

Comment: yes, I only want to prioritize the order of contributors with a role_code of A01 or B01.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I think that'll work, thanks!