# filtering the order_by relationship in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

In the below, product has many writers through contributor, and `contributor.role_code` defines the exact kind of contribution made to the product. Is it possible with the Django ORM to filter the contributors referenced by the order_by() method below? E.g. I want to order products only by contributors such that `contributor.role_code in ['A01', 'B01']`.

```
Product.objects.filter(
    product_type__name=choices.PRODUCT_BOOK
).order_by(
    'contributor__writer__last_name'    # filter which contributors it uses?
)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Do mean you want to obtain a list of products filtered by the `contributor.role_code`?

Comment: Not a list of products filtered by the `contributor.role_code`, but a list of products filtered by the product type, then *filter* or *limit* the order_by scope to contributors whose role_code are A01, then B01.

Comment: yekta is right. I mean can I order the products based on the last names of the writers of the contributors whose role_codes are A01 and B01, but not other contributors that would otherwise show up in that ordering?

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter/limit django order\_by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773764/filter-limit-django-order-by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via an annotation subquery:

1. Define the Subquery that represents the thing we want to order by
2. Annotate the original QuerySet with the Subquery
3. Order by the annotation.

```python
contributors_for_ordering = Contributor.objects.filter( # 1
    product=OuterRef('pk'),
    role_code__in=['A01', 'B01'],
).values('writer__last_name')

queryset = Product.objects.filter(
    product_type__name=choices.PRODUCT_BOOK
).annotate( # 2
    writer_last_name=Subquery(contributors_for_ordering[:1])  # Slice [:1] to ensure a single result
).order_by( # 3
    'writer_last_name'
)
```

Note, however, that there is a potential quirk here.  If a Product has contributors with both 'A01' and 'B01' we haven't controlled which one will be used for ordering--we'll get whichever the database returns first.  You can add an `order_by` clause to `contributors_for_ordering` to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

To filter on specific values, first build your list of accepted values:

```
accepted_values = ['A01', 'B01']
```

Then filter for values in this list:

```
Product.objects.filter(
        product_type__name=choices.PRODUCT_BOOK
    ).filter(
        contributor__role_code__in=accepted_values
    ).order_by(
        'contributor__writer__last_name'
    )
```

Comment: There are many contributors per product, unfrortunately, so this doesn't address the concern--I'm trying to make sure that in the order_by() call it's ordering based on the contributors who are A01 and B01, and not other contributors. This will filter the products but not affect which contributors are used for the ordering, IINM.